# How to visualize the elements as they are passed down from one vector to child vectors in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, visualization, graph-visualization

I will first start by introducing my problem.

I have a grand vector consisting of 20,000 elements:

```
Grand_Vector = c(1,5,26,153,73,41,64,15,78,23,5212,62,5231,532,52,64,2,52,75,32,525,11,42.......,7685,37)
```

I have other vectors called `smaller_vector1`, `smaller_vector2`, etc.. that COULD have some elements from `Grand_Vector`:

```
smaller_vector1 = c(1,11,6,26,33,13) # has 1, 26, and 26 from Grand_vector
smaller_vector2 = c(73,5231,2,52,7685,1111) # has 73, 5231, 7685 and 52 from Grand_vector
.
.
.
smaller_vector20 = c(26,153,73,41,64,15) # all the elements are from Grand_Vector
```

Now the issue is that, each of the `smaller_vector`s can have an even smaller vectors `tiny_vector`.

```
tiny_vector1 = c(1,11,20) # contains 1 and 11 from smaller_vector1
tiny_vector2 = c(6,26, 153, 41,1111)# contains elements from smaller_vector1, smaller_vector2, and smaller vector20
.
.
.
```

**All in all, I have 5 levels:**

1. Grand_Vector
2. smaller_vector's
3. tiny_vector's
4. tinier_vector's
5. tiniest_vector's

**GOAL: Visualize how the elements of `Grand_Vector` are passed down to the smaller vectors in a tree like structure with percentages of "similarity" with `Grand_Vector`**

I tried searching for a package that allows me to do so, but I am not sure it exists?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Each vector is in a separate variable? Can't you have them created in a matrix or list for each type (that would help the coding)?

Comment: I think you need to be more concrete about how you want the visualisation to look like? Is it like alluvial diagram?

Comment: This is going to be cumbersome if your vectors aren't in lists. A hint would be that the similarity proportion would be given by `length(which(smaller_vector1 %in% Grand_Vector))/length(smaller_vector1)` . To generate a tree-like structure for this many elements you will probably need a recursive function, and that will require that your data are stored in a list (or at least one list per level)

Answer (score 0):

If your vectors aren't in lists, you need to use `get(paste(...))` inside every loop to get the vector, which isn't ideal. But check if that works:

```
proportions = list()
for(a in 1:n_smaller_vector){#n is the number of smaller vectors you have
  smaller_vector = get(paste("smaller_vector", a, sep=""))
  proportions[[a]] = sum(smaller_vector %in% grand_vector)/length(grand_vector)
  
  for(b in 1:n_tiny_vector){
    tiny_vector = get(paste("tiny_vector", a, sep=""))
    proportions[[a]][[b]] = sum(tiny_vector %in% smaller_vector)/length(smaller_vector)
    
    for(c in 1:n_tinier_vector){
      tinier_vector = get(paste("tinier_vector", a, sep=""))
      proportions[[a]][[b]][[c]] = sum(tinier_vector %in% tiny_vector)/length(tiny_vector)
      
      for(d in 1:n_tiniest_vector){
        tiniest_vector = get(paste("tiniest_vector", a, sep=""))
        proportions[[a]][[b]][[c]][[d]] = sum(tiniest_vector %in% tinier_vector)/length(tinier_vector)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The same thing but giving names to the list:

```
proportions = list()
for(a in 1:n_smaller_vector){#n is the number of smaller vectors you have
  name_a = paste("smaller_vector", a, sep="")
  smaller_vector = get(name_a)
  proportions[[name_a]] = sum(smaller_vector %in% grand_vector)/length(grand_vector)
  
  for(b in 1:n_tiny_vector){
    name_b = paste("tiny_vector", a, sep="")
    tiny_vector = get(name_b)
    proportions[[name_a]][[name_b]] = sum(tiny_vector %in% smaller_vector)/length(smaller_vector)
    
    for(c in 1:n_tinier_vector){
      name_c = paste("tinier_vector", a, sep="")
      tinier_vector = get(name_c)
      proportions[[name_a]][[name_b]][[name_c]] = sum(tinier_vector %in% tiny_vector)/length(tiny_vector)
      
      for(d in 1:n_tiniest_vector){
        name_d = paste("tiniest_vector", a, sep="")
        tiniest_vector = get(name_d)
        proportions[[name_a]][[name_b]][[name_c]][[name_d]] = sum(tiniest_vector %in% tinier_vector)/length(tinier_vector)
      }
    }
  }
}
```